# Probability and Stats - understanding the sample variance formula

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to find the sample standard deviation of a sample space of n=100. I am doing this by using the formula for sample variance:

$$(1/n-1)\sum_{i=1}^{100}(Yi - Ybar)^2$$

and then taking the square root of that value. However, I am encountering something that seems odd in the solutions manual. I wanted some insight to make sure I am not misinterpreting this equation.

A random sample of 100 foxes was examined by a team of veterinarians
to determine the prevalence of a specic parasite. Counting the number of parasites
of this specic type, the veterinarians found that 69 foxes had no parasites of the
type of interest, 17 had one parasite of the type under study, and so on. A summary
of their results is given in the following table:

$$Parasites = 0/ 1/ 2/ 3/ 4/ 5/ 6/ 7/ 8$$
$$Foxes = 69/ 17/ 6/ 3/ 1/ 2/ 1/  1$$

(If anyone knows how to reformat that into a table please do! I did my best to make the data appear organized. Read it this way: 69 foxes had 0 parasites. 17 foxes had 1 parasite. etc.)

I thought I should solve it this way:

$$(1/99)\sum_{i=1}^{100}((69*0)-.66)^2)+((17*(1-.66)^2)....$$

where $Ybar=.66$

However, this is the suggested method:

$$(1/99)\sum_{i=1}^{100}(69*(0-.66)^2)+(17*(-.66)^2)....$$

I am a bit confused why the suggested method better fits the general formula for sample variance than the way i thought I should solve this question. I solved mine and got an answer significantly different than the suggested solution. Can anyone educate me?

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions? I know these are easy calculations - I guess i'm just looking at the (Yi-Ybar) part incorrectly...or the suggested solution is wrong. I really want to understand this.

Answer (score 0):

The sample standard deviation is the sum of squared deviations for *each* datapoint. Neither of your formulas make much sense to me. The "suggested" formula is nonsense, wheres your formula is mostly correct, but we should fix some notation/concepts:

Your data consists of pairs (No Parasites, No. Foxes). If you want the variance of the number of parasites on a single fox, then your answer would be:

$\frac{1}{99}\sum\limits_{i=0}^8 N_i(i-\bar Y)^2$ where $N_i$ is the number of foxes with $i$ parasites, and $\bar Y$ is the average number of parasites on a fox.